# excel vba if cell contains value print area in excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I am trying to use vba code to print an area of excel (AC120:AT128) when a cell value contains "X"
At the moment my code prints out the whole spread sheet but I only want it to print out the selected cell area.

Can someone please show me how I can achieve this? thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim celltxt As String
celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("AQ98").Text
If InStr(1, celltxt, "X") Then

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In Worksheets
 If ws.Range("AQ98") = "X" Then
 ws.PrintOut
 End If
 Next ws

Else

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of Excel you're using, but in Office 2010, you can simply use.

`Range("AC120:AT128").PrintOut()`

Or

`Selection.PrintOut()`

You can also use the set print area function, e.g.

`ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = "AC120:AT128"`

Comment: thanks im using 2010, where abouts in my line of code would I place this please?

Comment: If I've understood what you trying to achieve, you should be able to remove the "ws.PrintOut" line and replace it with the "Range("AC120:AT128").PrintOut" line.

Comment: yea I managed to do that thanks for your help, one last thing am I able to tell it to print the page in portrait?

Comment: ws.PageSetup.Orientation=xlLandscape or ws.PageSetup.Orientation=xlPortrait